# I have a 404 error on all my pages! What do I do?

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I have changed default permalinks into custom structure, and I got 404 error across all of my site.

Comment: I assume you changed the permalinks using `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`, and assuming you ticked `Custom Structure` option, can instead switch  to `Plain` and see if that will restore the contents?

Comment: Can you share your custom permalink structure? There's very little information in your question, at the moment it's not possible to answer it, please provide as much detail as you possibly can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset your permalink structure. In your WordPress Dashboard go to Settings > Permalinks. All custom post types require [additional slugs](https://helpcenter.qodeinteractive.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002252638-How-To-Change-The-Permalink-Slugs-For-Your-Custom-Posts) like /portfolio-item/, /destination-item/, /tour-item/, /property-item/, /listing/ etc. So you probably made a typo in your custom structure. Select an alternative permalinks structure -> Save Changes. Change it back to your standard structure and hit Save Changes once again.
If you’re still getting a “404 Page Not Found” error, try [other remaining methods](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/wordpress-broken-permalinks/).

[image: permalink slug]

Answer (score 0):

You can try run "mysql" for basic default config "options-permalink.php"

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = '' WHERE `option_name` = 'permalink_structure';
```

or

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = '/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/' WHERE `option_name` = 'permalink_structure';
```